# Is there a way to log found values in Detox?

Tags: javascript, end-to-end, detox

I'm trying to debug some Detox tests, I've got some assertions like the following:

```
await expect(eventScreenMatcher.component).toExist();
await expect(eventScreenMatcher.toggleButton).toExist();
await expect(eventScreenMatcher.toggleButton).toHaveText('Add to schedule');
```

The button that I believe is the `toggleButton` is on screen and has the correct text `Add to schedule`. But Detox is failing on that last assertion.

How does Detox determine what the text is (does it just check that element) and is there a way to log what it thinks is there?

This is the output I currently get:

> Expected: (with text: is "Add to schedule" and view has effective visibility=VISIBLE)
> Got: "ReactViewGroup{id=4605, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1300, height=139, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams@34f98eb, tag=ToggleScheduleButton, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ‘getAttributes()’ method? It can be a little tricky sometimes but I think it would help solve your problem.
https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/actions-on-element/#getattributes

Then you could try something like

```
const buttonAttributes = await eventScreenMatcher.toggleButton.getAttributes();

await jestExpect(buttonAttributes.text).toBe('Add to Schedule');
```